# insert cmr values into database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, csv

I have a CMR file with different values, but I don't know how to use the separator.
I want to store "numberPacketsLost", "jitter", and "latency" into a mySQL database using java netbeans with button.

Thanks! :)

Code from cmr file :

```
"cdrRecordType","globalCallID_callManagerId","globalCallID_callId","nodeId","directoryNum","callIdentifier","dateTimeStamp","numberPacketsSent","numberOctetsSent","numberPacketsReceived","numberOctetsReceived","numberPacketsLost","jitter","latency","pkid","directoryNumPartition","globalCallId_ClusterID","deviceName","varVQMetrics"
INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(129),VARCHAR(600)
2,2,1732470,2,"4241",47660016,1319556369,192,33024,191,32852,0,0,0,"8ea4f719-c49c-4456-a2a8-972ebcfb57a9","2b494acb-9359-7f52-b0ef-7b66bb672b73","StandAloneCluster","SEP0026CB3C2A16","MLQK=0.0000;MLQKav=0.0000;MLQKmn=0.0000;MLQKmx=0.0000;ICR=0.0000;CCR=0.0000;ICRmx=0.0000;CS=0;SCS=0;MLQKvr=0.95"
2,2,1732447,2,"5352",47659963,1319556371,1409,242348,1408,242176,0,0,0,"61ca6d9f-8e75-4282-b303-3fea2fa75df7","2b494acb-9359-7f52-b0ef-7b66bb672b73","StandAloneCluster","SEP64168D506D26","MLQK=4.5000;MLQKav=4.3554;MLQKmn=4.1440;MLQKmx=4.5000;ICR=0.0000;CCR=0.0029;ICRmx=0.0263;CS=1;SCS=1;MLQKvr=0.95"
2,2,1732134,2,"5502",47658367,1319556373,28529,4906988,28537,4908364,0,0,0,"d1717925-89bf-41b4-b122-6162db89128f","2b494acb-9359-7f52-b0ef-7b66bb672b73","StandAloneCluster","SEP64168D50A4DB","MLQK=4.5000;MLQKav=4.4570;MLQKmn=4.1440;MLQKmx=4.5000;MLQKvr=0.95;CCR=0.0011;ICR=0.0000;ICRmx=0.0267;CS=9;SCS=9"
```

Comment: yes !! i need the java code to extract the data !!

Comment: Can you do any of the parts you mentioned? read from a file, split the String, write a mySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up the cmr file, read through it line by line skipping the headers and extract the data. Once you get the needed data, just write a query to insert into the database.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("myCmrFile")));
String line = null;
int linecount = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    if (linecount++ < 2) // skip the headers
        continue;
    // split the data and convert to integers
    String[] data = line.split(",");
    Integer packetsLost = Integer.valueOf(data[10]); 
    Integer jitter = Integer.valueOf(data[11]); 
    Integer latency = Integer.valueOf(data[12]); 
    // now insert into the db, query will look something like this
    String query = "INSERT INTO myTable (numberPacketsLost, jitter, latency) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatment(query);
    ps.setInt(1, packetsLost);
    ps.setInt(2, jitter);
    ps.setInt(3, latency);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

This code won't work exactly, you will need to change it around based on the real values of your database.

Comment: thank you :) for help ^^, but i want to create table automatically from the cmr file then i insert the 3 values to it, if i can how to do it !! my database is mysql, i work with mysql workbench !! thanks again :)

Comment: the problem is that the second line is Data-type block the integer values from insertion into base !!

Comment: when i click in the button in application i have this message :

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:""numberPacketLost""

Comment: You need to skip the headers. So skip one more line

Comment: now the message change : java.sql.SQLException: NO value specified for parameter 1 !!

Comment: It's b/c this was not complete code.  I updated the answer with how you should set the values with the PreparedStatment syntax

Comment: now the error message: java.sql.SQLException:Can not issue data manipulation statements with excuteQuery()

Comment: Change it to executeUpdate()

Comment: now : java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server :"duplicate entry"for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: Then you are inserting a duplicate key, you can do an insert ignore, insert on duplicate key update, or numerous other things to handle that problem

Comment: You really need to just learn mysql and java, I can't give you a step by step tutorial for everything you can do with code

Comment: good luck Jomni! it will all click when you are bit more practiced :)

Comment: thanks for all , i appreciate your help :) good luck you too :)

Comment: hi again , i have an error: java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception:10                           seems to be the value packets Lost i guess !!

Comment: You might have a line that is shorter than the rest, or that line isn't splittable, it might be empty.

Comment: i want to insert dateTimeStamp from file into database with "human date" (convert and insert it), how to do that ?! , thanks :)